# How to Start two activity with one Launcher icon?

Tags: android, app-launcher

I want to open two activity with the same icon by the some of my app preference. Can
any one tell me how to do that at runtime?

Comment: It is not possible....It would be better if you would have tell what you really want to achieve...

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You can only have one Activity with the required intent-filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

What you could do is launch a splash screen, and then check your preferences in that. Depending on the prefs, you can then launch the appropriate activity.